# Difference between "underlying" and "underneath"

Tags: difference, word-difference

I'm having a hard time figuring out the difference between under**lying** and under**neath**...

---

For instance, The Free Dictionary definition for both wasn't helpful:

> [Lying under or beneath something](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underlying)

and

> [In or to a place beneath; below](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underneath)

Also, I couldn't find any particular difference *Google searching* for ["it uses * underlying"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+uses+*+underlying%22) and ["it uses * underneath"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+uses+*+underneath%22).

Comment: Have you tried looking them up in a dictionary?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com) gives "Lying under or beneath something" for one and "In or to a place beneath; below" for the other. Not much of a difference for me.

Comment: I have never heard "underlying" defined that way. I usually hear it used as "to be the foundation, cause, or basis of". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlie

Comment: What is more confusing is the difference between underlying and underpinning, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semantically they're very similar, but syntactically, the difference is that [***underlying***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlying) is an *adjective*, whereas [***underneath***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underneath) is either a *preposition* or an *adverb*.

The syntactic difference means that, like most adjectives, ***underlying*** usually occurs *before* the noun it modifies...

> *This sentence illustrates my underlying point.*

...but note that we can also use it as a "continuous verb form", with "point" as the *subject*...

> *The point underlying that sentence is made again here.*

---

Apart from that syntactic difference, note that the relatively less common ***underlying*** usually refers to something *fundamental*, that *underpins* something else, whereas ***underneath*** (and plain ***under***) merely implies something being (physical or figuratively) *below* something else.

Comment: Great answer. In my *Google search example*, "it uses *something* underneath" would be the correct way to phrase it?

Comment: @talles: I don't know what you're trying to say there. You'd need to explain the exact *context* in which you might be uncertain about which word to use. In most cases if you give a full sentence, only one would be valid, or the meaning would change according to which word you used.

Comment: @FumbleFigers In my case *something* is a *software* (a [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) to be more specific).

Comment: @talles - It's a thorny question question when applied to software, for a couple reasons. (1) Software isn't physical, so the sense of "under" doesn't apply (not in the sense of one is _on top_, the other is _under_). (2) Software is relatively new (software libraries even more so), so there isn't as much precedent for how words like _beneath_ would apply.

Comment: In any case, this is why we implore people to include [**Details**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) in their questions. By itself, "What is the difference between _underlying_ and _underneath_?" can go a few different ways (the first of which is, "What does the dictionary say?"). Of the many ways to answer that question, most of them won't help you determine whether a software library is running _underneath_ a system, or if we should say something about the _underlying_ code in a library. (It's best not to ask about "somethings" when you have something more specific in mind.)

Comment: @talles: You give very little context, but let's suppose you want to say something about the importance of your great software library, which is used by the development teams behind many popular applications. You'd probably say it ***underpins*** those apps, not that it's an *underlying* component (you certainly wouldn't say it *underlies* them). Underlying things are like seeds in soil - they *inherently* give rise to what we see on top. Underpinning just provides a foundation for anything that happens to need that kind of (possibly figurative) "base".